# Upload file to Cloud Storage for Firebase with Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I want to add files to my Google Cloud Storage (actually a Firebase bucket) using a java server.

I am using this code i got on the internet:

```
    // Authenticate using a service account
    Storage storage;
    try {
        storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:/tmp/firebasekey.json")))
                .build()
                .getService();
        // The name for the new bucket
        String bucketName = "MinhaSaude";

        // Creates the new bucket
        Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));
        // Create blob
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob_name");
        // Add metadata to the blob
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
        // Upload blob to GCS (same as Firebase Storage)
        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I receive back is erros after `Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));`

Either "Invalid bucket name: 'MinhaSaude'"
}

or "The account for bucket "minhasaude-api" has been disabled."

I cant find a bucketname that satisfies google. I already uploaded a file to Firebase using browser and its uploading ok.

Comment: Can you link to where you found your code online?

Comment: I removed the tags for Firebase because this is purely Cloud Storage SDK code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with my code, its works for me

```
String filename =  httpRequest.getFirstQueryParameter("name").get();
    String contentType =  httpRequest.getFirstQueryParameter("content-type").get();

    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("key.json").getFile());
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(file);

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setStorageBucket("<you bucket name>")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    Bucket bucket = StorageClient.getInstance(firebaseApp).bucket();


    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("firebaseId")
            .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(file)))
            .build()
            .getService();
    file = new File(classLoader.getResource("jar-loading.gif").getFile());

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucket.getName(), filename)
            .setContentType(contentType).build();

    try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int limit;
        try {
            while ((limit = inputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, limit));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle exception
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

With that code I could upload gif file from my project to firebase storage. Make change to use it

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are buckets that you have created previously? Try a random string of letters and see if that works.

Alternately, one can only create GCS buckets when billing has been enabled for your GCS project. Have you set up your project with a credit card and whatnot?